# Verifying Composition Method algorthm for Random Variable generation

Tags: python, variables, random, simulation, composition

I´m working on implementing the composition method algorithm that states the following:

**Composition Approach**
Another method for generating rando variables is the composition approach. Suppose that X has CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function) Fx and we wish to simulate a value of X.

We can write

[image]

Where the Fj´s are also CDF´s and pj>0 for all j and Sum(Pj)=1

**Composition Algorithm:**

```
1. Generate I distributed on the non-negative integers so that:

    P(I=j) = Pj
2. If I = j, then simulate Yj from Fj

3. Set X= Yj
```

Here´s my implementation in python, the part I´m not sure about is when I set

```
Yj = F[j](random.random())
```

Because I think I should be using the inverse of F[j]. I would like to get some clarification on whether the above  line is correct or not.

Here´s the rest of the algorithm:

```
def composition_method(F,p):
X =[None]*len(p) #Inicializando list of size p
cont=True
while(cont):
    for j in range (0,len(p)):
        #1.Generate I, non negative integer sych that  P(I=j)= Pj
        I = inverse_transform(p)
        #2. if I=j, simulate Yj from Fj
        if(I=j):
            Yj = F[j](random.random())
            #3. Sets X= Yj 
            X[j]=Yj
    cont = False     
    #4. Verififying x does not have None elements
    for(elm in X):
        if(elm==None):
            cont =True
```

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I´ve edited the question to make it clearer. Please let me know if I have to make any other change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The F<sub>j</sub>'s are cumulative distribution functions chosen for two properties.  1) Together, with the appropriate weightings, they make up the F<sub>x</sub> you're interested in, and 2) They should themselves be easy to generate from.  The most common way would be to use [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).  Another possibility would be [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions). The details would depend on the specific set of F<sub>j</sub>'s.

If you're not familiar with either inversion or convolution, you really shouldn't be jumping into composition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  so what I´m generating on my function is a random variable X with the cumulative distribution Fx I mentioned? Or do I still have some errors in my code?

Comment: If you've correctly constructed your composition, you should end up with Fx.  Your specific code looks wrong, though.  When you generate a value `I`, that means that you should be using the `I`th CDF function to generate the next `X` value via some suitable method.  It *doesn't* mean generate an `X` conditional on `I` matching the current loop index.

Comment: See page 59 of [this tutorial paper](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc07papers/007.pdf) for a specific examples of how to generate a simple triangle distribution using a variety of alternative techniques, including composition.

Comment: Thanks pjs you really helped me here. I will remove the conditional statement and use I as the index of F to generate X. I´ve realized it is impossible to make this method work with any Fi as a lambda expression in python since I cannot use inversion(which is the only method I´m allowed to use) on all cdf´s. Thanks again

Comment: @PabloEstrada Glad to help. You may still be able to use lambdas if you interpret the algorithm as "generate an X from the distribution with CDF I". In that case your lambda's would be any appropriate generating mechanism -- inversion, convolution, composition, acceptance/rejection, or even another composition.